# Gitlab AutoDevOps Angular

Tags: gitlab

I have a freshly new Angular project that I've pushed on my self hosted Gitlab instance. 
I have enable AutoDevOps and run a pipeline but the build stage is stuck on the step 5/11 (buildpack) during the build process.

```
Step 5/11 : RUN /bin/herokuish buildpack build
 ---> Running in 16d521d8adbf
       -----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.13.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.12.1

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
```

After ~15min the job end with a `job succeeded` message but it didn't pass the 5th step (and so the create dpod is missing the docker image).

I wanted to update the gitlab-ci yml file of the AutoDevOps but the build script is using `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable` so I'm not able to update the script.

Any idea why the build is being stuck on installing dependencies ? If it's a kind of timeout is their any parameters I can tweak ?

Comment: Is your executor behind proxy? Did you try executing your build script manually on gitlab runner instance?

Comment: Yes my kubernetes cluster is behind an NGINX LoadBalancer. And how do you run the script "manually" on the gitlab runner ?

Comment: I assumed that you have beside self hosted gitlab, self hosted infrastructure so it should be possible to connect to your executor, reproduce manually build steps and check if everything works fine when you run it step by step. Was this autodeploy script working for you ever before? If you suspect that it might be due to installation of dependencies timeout you could check if simpler version of project with less dependencies works. Anyway it is weird that your build quits at step 5/11 and still passes. What is your gitlab version?